# GitHub Action to build environment variables from each other

Tags: environment-variables, github-actions

In GitHub Action, how to build environment variables one after another:

```yaml
name: workflow-level-custom-environment-variables

on: [push]
# Here the environment variable is declared in workflow level
env:
    PART1: var1
    PART2: ${PART1}var2
    PUBLICENV: ${PART2} Available for all jobs in this workflow
```

This can be really useful, for e.g., here is a real-life example from **`Dockerfile`**:

```
ARG JMETER_VERSION="5.4.2"
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
```

I know `Dockerfile` is not GitHub Action, but I'm just showing the principle when it can be useful.

Comment: No, I have not tried Solution myself. But I read it in github action's documentation. here : docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables

Comment: Does it have to be at the workflow level? Because you can use the `>> $GITHUB_ENV` with shell commands at the step level (which would be easier).

Comment: @GuiFalourd, yeah, I figure that might be the only option, as the "solution" that I found was doing just that -- https://brandur.org/fragments/github-actions-env-vars-in-env-vars, it requires that different assignments needs to be in different steps, of which I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

@xpt I've build a github action for this purpose where you can subtitute and combine variables and scope to specific environments. Maybe of some use for your scenario -> https://github.com/jnus/json-variables

Comment: That looks promising, but at the moment, I just want to use only environment variables, not any json files. Thanks for the info though!